# Trouble bulkifying an apex scheduled class

Tags: apex, query, scheduled-apex, governorlimits

I made a scheduled class which gave me the error soql limit exeeded I following got the error too many query rows. Now I have the error:CPU time limit exceeded. How can in bulkify my class correctly

Before:

```
global class RenewalValueOpp  implements Schedulable{
  global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    List<Opportunity> RenewalValue=[SELECT Id,Opportunity.Name, (SELECT Id FROM Orders__r) 
                                    FROM Opportunity 
                                    WHERE CreatedBy.Name='Man' AND CreatedDate=Yesterday AND Type='Renewal'];//TODAY
    system.debug('RenewalValue van Opportunity'+RenewalValue);
    for(Opportunity r : RenewalValue){
      double TotOrder = 0;

      List<Order__c> OrderAmount =[SELECT id, Order_Amount__c FROM Order__c WHERE Opportunity_Name__r.Id=:r.Id];

      System.debug('OrderAmount '+ OrderAmount);
        for(Order__c o : OrderAmount){ 
          TotOrder += o.Order_Amount__c; 
        }  
       r.Renewal_Value__c=TotOrder;
       System.debug('r.Renewal_Value__c   TotOrder'+ r.Renewal_Value__c);
       Update r;
     }
  }
}
```

After

```
global class RenewalValueOpp  implements Schedulable{
    public Opportunity r;
      global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {

        List<Opportunity> RenewalValue=[SELECT Id,Opportunity.Name, (SELECT Id FROM Orders__r) 
                                        FROM Opportunity 
                                        WHERE CreatedBy.Name='Man' AND CreatedDate=Yesterday AND Type='Renewal'];//TODAY
          List<Order__c> OrderAmount =[SELECT id,Opportunity_Name__r.Id, Order_Amount__c FROM Order__c WHERE CreatedDate=Yesterday];      
          system.debug('RenewalValue van Opportunity'+RenewalValue);
        for(Opportunity r : RenewalValue){
          double TotOrder = 0;
          System.debug('OrderAmount '+ OrderAmount);
            for(Order__c o : OrderAmount){ 
                if(o.Opportunity_Name__r.Id==r.id){
              TotOrder += o.Order_Amount__c; 
                    }
            }  
           r.Renewal_Value__c=TotOrder;
           System.debug('r.Renewal_Value__c   TotOrder'+ r.Renewal_Value__c);

         }
          Update r;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67522/discussion-on-question-by-latifa-trouble-bulkifying-an-apex-scheduled-class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the relationship is master details, we can always create a roll-up summary field to get aggregate of all the values of a certain field of child records. This should be the best solution suggested.

[image]

Considering the scheduled update, you can go ahead with the code as below.

```
Map<String,double> mapOppIdToOrderAmount = new Map<String,double>();
List<Opportunity> lstOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();

for(Order__c objOrder : [SELECT Opportunity_Name__c, Order_Amount__c 
                                 FROM Order__c WHERE CreatedDate=TODAY]){

    double dblOrderAmount = 0;
    if(mapOppIdToOrderAmount.containsKey(objOrder.Opportunity_Name__c)){

        dblOrderAmount = mapOppIdToOrderAmount.get(objOrder.Opportunity_Name__c) + objOrder.Order_Amount__c;
    }    
    dblOrderAmount += objOrder.Order_Amount__c;


    mapOppIdToOrderAmount.put(objOrder.Opportunity_Name__c,dblOrderAmount);
}

for(Opportunity objOpportunity : [SELECT Id, Renewal_Value__c
                                    FROM   Opportunity 
                                    WHERE  Id =: mapOppIdToOrderAmount.keySet()]){

    objOpportunity.Renewal_Value__c = (objOpportunity.Renewal_Value__c != null) ? objOpportunity.Renewal_Value__c : Double.valueOf(0);
    if(mapOppIdToOrderAmount.containsKey(objOpportunity.Id)){       

        objOpportunity.Renewal_Value__c += mapOppIdToOrderAmount.get(objOpportunity.Id);
        lstOpportunity.add(objOpportunity);
    }
}

if(!lstOpportunity.isEmpty()){

    update lstOpportunity;
}
```

Follow [Apex best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices). few specifics:

1. avoid using nested loop, instead use collections.
2. bulkify code to handle multiple records.

The **best solution** will always be going with clicks over code which results in same desired result.